# Lubuntu 14.04 no sound, can't install pulseaudio

Tags: 14.04, sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

I have two PCs I've installed LUbuntu 14.04 on. On one sound is fine and pulseaudio was installed during the OS installation. On the other pulseaudio is missing, and there is no sound at all, not from audio jack nor from HDMI.
When typing `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio` I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pulseaudio : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:4.0-0ubuntu11) but 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 is to be installed
              Recommends: pulseaudio-module-x11 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: rtkit but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy pulseaudio`

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install libpulse0=1:4.0-0ubuntu11` and then try again to install `pulseaudio`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to install the `pulseaudio (1:4.0-0ubuntu11)` from the `trusty` repositories. But you have enabled `trusty-updates`, therefore `libpulse0 (1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1)` is to be installed.

The only explanation is that you have forgotten to start the command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After that

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio
```

and to upgrade the whole system

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: I installed pulseaudio as suggested in the last comment to my question before you posted. Sound kind of works. Then did what you said as well. Sound works, which is a progress, but stuttery and poppy if from HDMI. If from audio jack (headphones) it is OK, What have I done wrong or missing?

Comment: Sorry, but that's a new question.

Comment: The answer is here http://askubuntu.com/questions/676301/choppy-poppy-audio-via-hdmi-alsa-pulseaudio#autocomment980034

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove libpulse0

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And then try to install pulseaudio

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

I had the same issue, but this helped for me.