# Can't install pulseaudio on lubuntu 14.04 (for no sound in skype)

Tags: lubuntu, pulseaudio, skype, gcc

This is not a duplicate, none of the solutions offered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676283/lubuntu-14-04-no-sound-cant-install-pulseaudio) could solve my problem. Basically, what happens is:

```
***@***:~$ sudo aptitude install pulseaudio
[sudo] password for *** : 

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio{a} libfftw3-single3{a} libgomp1{ab} libpulsedsp{a} pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-x11{a} pulseaudio-utils{a} rtkit{a}

0 packages upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Need to get 1.673 kB of archives. After unpacking 6.842 kB will be used.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is installed.

open: 25; closed: 247; defer: 17; conflict:     27  
                                                                                                                            .The following actions  will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libfftw3-single3 [Not Installed]                   
2)     libgomp1 [Not Installed]                           
3)     pulseaudio [Not Installed]                         
4)     pulseaudio-module-x11 [Not Installed]              



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Remove the following packages:                                                        
1)      gcc-4.8-base:i386                                                                   
2)      libdbusmenu-qt2:i386                                                                
3)      libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:i386                                                      
4)      libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386                                                      
5)      libjack-jackd2-0:i386                                                               
6)      libllvm3.6:i386                                                                     
7)      libqt4-dbus:i386                                                                    
8)      libqt4-declarative:i386                                                             
9)      libqt4-network:i386                                                                 
10)     libqt4-opengl:i386                                                                  
11)     libqt4-script:i386                                                                  
'12)     libqt4-sql:i386                                                                     
13)     libqt4-sql-mysql:i386                                                               
14)     libqt4-xml:i386                                                                     
15)     libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386                                                             
16)     libqtcore4:i386                                                                     
17)     libqtdbus4:i386                                                                     
18)     libqtgui4:i386                                                                      
19)     libqtwebkit4:i386                                                                   
20)     libstdc++6:i386                                                                     
21)     libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386                                                              
22)     skype                                                                               
23)     skype-bin:i386                                                                      
24)     sni-qt:i386                                                                         

      Downgrade the following packages:                                                     
25)     cpp-4.8 [4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 (now) -> 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 (trusty)]                    
26)     gcc-4.8-base [4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 (now) -> 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 (trusty)]               
27)     libquadmath0 [4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 (now) -> 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 (trusty)]               
28)     libstdc++6 [4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 (now) -> 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 (trusty)]                 

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                                          
29)     skype-bin:i386 recommends sni-qt:i386                                               
30)     libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:i386 recommends libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 | libtxc-dxtn0:i386


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

I know the second solution will mess up everything, and I have no idea how to work this around.

Sorry if my question violates or doesn't satisfy some criteria. I'll be glad to edit it if needed.

EDIT: I've just noticed the error

```
libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is installed
```

makes it impossible to install anything else. I've just tried installing texlive-full and kile and had it as error.

Comment: What's the response of a simple `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson it outputs: 

    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Ok.. Then try: `sudo apt-get install libgomp1=4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04`

Comment: The result was: 

'E: Version '4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04' for 'libgomp1' was not found'

Comment: Open _Software & Updates_, select the _Updates_ tab, and make sure that **trusty-updates** is enabled. Then choose _Reload_ when closing the tool.

Comment: Actually it's already checked. I did uncheck and checked again just so I could reload though, but nothing. I'm considering doing the downgrades, but i'm pretty afraid it'll mess up my installation. :/

Comment: Given what you now have told us, I suspect that - for some reason - libgomp1 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is missing on the mirror you use. So my next suggestion is to open _Software & Updates_ again and change the download server to "Main server".

Comment: That was it, Gunnar! I was using a local brazilian mirror (locaweb), and by moving back to Main I could finally have 'pulseaudio' installed. Thank you A LOT. It's a pitty I can't chose your help as an answer.

Comment: Great to hear that. :) As regards an answer, I'd suggest that you submit an own answer with the solution and mark it as the best one, so others see that the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the comments, It's seen that thanks to [Gunnar Hjalmarsson](https://askubuntu.com/users/159370/gunnar-hjalmarsson) I could solve my problem by simply going to *Software & Updates* and selecting "Main server" instead of using my local mirror "locaweb" (from Brazil).

Thanks, Gunnar!